# Reading from a binary file with a given data structure

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, struct, binaryfiles

I want to read the 'Last Traded Price' from the given binary file. How do I extract a specific data out of the file by using notations like 'hhl10s6sc'. I know I have to use the struct.unpack method, but where can I learn to write such formatting (with some illustrations) so that I can extract any data that I want from such a binary file.

The thing that is troubling me is the unpacking that the writer of the code (that I'm trying to understand) has written - 'hlhcl6s10s11s10s2s1s10s12schc' . I understood what 6s...12s mean, but what's the significance of the 'hlhcl' (5 characters in the beginning) and 'chc' (3 characters in the last). The writer has tried to retrieve the 'Last traded price' from the data structure.

If you could give some examples and/or some sources for the same, it'd be very helpful. Attached the image which contains the data structure of the given file.

[This image shows the data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTLID.png)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib2.html#working-with-binary-data-record-layouts
Looking up the documentation would've been far less effort than writing this question.

Comment: I already looked up the documentation, but it does not have enough examples for me to understand the method of writing.

Comment: There are at least three other guides on the first page of googling "python struct tutorial". What exactly makes your question distinct from any of them? Even if I wanted to spend the time, I can't exactly personalize something based on no input about why it's troubling you.

Comment: The thing that is troubling me is the unpacking that the writer of the code  (that I'm trying to understand) has written. 'hlhcl6s10s11s10s2s1s10s12schc' . I understood what 6s...12s mean, but what's the significance of the 'hlhcl' (5 characters in the beginning) and 'chc' (3 characters in the last). The writes has tried to retrieve the 'Last traded price' from the data structure. Sorry if it is bothering you. Please skip the question if that's too stupid for you. I hope every beginner learns by making mistakes (which I've done by asking this apparently stupid question , according to you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`struct` format strings are fields described in order. Every letter is a [format character](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters), so `hlhcl` translates to "short, long, short, character, long". This doesn't resemble the image you linked (which is a tad impractical as it's off-site and another step to look up), which starts with a single long and otherwise holds only strings. It might apply to a protocol wrapping that packet.